# List all available tags in Cucumber

Tags: cucumber

Is there a command line option to list all the tags in your cucumber test suite?

For example, I would want something like:

```
cucumber --show-tags foo.feature
```

That would give me something like:

```
@ci
@development
@regression
@wip
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a single file:

```
cucumber -f tag_cloud foo.feature
```

You could also find the tags of all features in a directory:

```
cucumber -f tag_cloud features/login
```

Or even features that are shared with a particular tag:

```
cucumber --format tag_cloud --tags @bvt
```

The output generated for all these is a wiki style table:

```
| @baseline | @customer | @demographics | @performance |
| 1         | 1         | 1             | 1            |
```

Comment: With cucumber version 1.2.1 this seems not to work anymore. Any ideas on how to get that list of used tags?

Comment: You can find the more current answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/18455872/111995 (code and instructions to create custom formatter)