# Is there any cucumber command to get all the scenario names?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, bdd

I have more than 1K scenarios in my repository, and i need to get all the scenario names and its folder path to prepare a report.

It will helpful for me, if any cucumber command to get all the scenario names and folder path.

Comment: I'm not sure it specifically answers your question, but I found this helpful a while ago so it may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18442904/fetching-tags-from-a-feature-file-using-cucumber/18455872#18455872

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a more succinct way of finding the answers, other than perhaps shell scripting.

Comment: yard-cucumber works for me. I've also used shell scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a cucumber command, but a simple shell search seemed to yield good results for me.

```
grep -r 'Feature' path-to-directory
./features/a_feature.feature:Feature: This is the first feature returned.
```